# jQuery each "sleep" with callback inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, each, sleep

I have an each() with inside a function with callback. 
I would like that each() will be synchronous by callback.
I post here my example

```js
function insRow(rif, callback){
    setTimeout(function() { 
      $(rif+" tr:nth-child(2)");
      var newtr=$(rif+" tr:nth-child(2)").clone();
      $(".insTo").append(newtr);
      $(rif+" tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)").text("O");
      $(rif+" tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)").text("O");
      $(rif+" tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(5)").text("O");
      if (callback) { callback(true); }
    },1000);
}

var go=true;
$(".insFrom tr:not(:first-child)").each(function(){
    if(go){
        go=false;
        $(".middle tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)").text($(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text());
        $(".middle tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)").text($(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text());
        $(".middle tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(5)").text($(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").text());
        insRow(".middle", function(callback){
          if(callback){                                                        
            go=true;
          }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
table td{
  border:1px solid black;
  min-width:50px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="insTo">
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td></tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<table class="middle">
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td></tr>
<tr><td>O/td><td>X</td><td>O</td><td>Y</td><td>O</td></tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<table class="insFrom">
<tr><td>A</td><td>C</td><td>E</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
```

My code is more complicated than this and I must to pass data from "insFrom" to "middle" and than combined to "insTo". Now my result is only the first row combined, but I want to have all combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to await the loop (this is new cool js stuff [ won't work in old browsers]):

```
//we need to define a block of async code
(async function (){
  //.forEach won't work, we need a real array and a real for loop
  for(const el of $(".insFrom tr:not(:first-child)").toArray()){

    $(".middle tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)").text($(el).find("td:nth-child(1)").text());
    $(".middle tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)").text($(el).find("td:nth-child(2)").text());
    $(".middle tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(5)").text($(el).find("td:nth-child(3)").text());

    //now the real magic:
    //the code halts here, and resumes when the callback gets called        
    await new Promise(callback => insRow(".middle", callback));
  }
})();//the async code block is called emmidiately
```

Or you need some callback hell:

```
var els = $(".insFrom tr:not(:first-child)");
//an IIFE, used as an entry point for continuing
(function next(i){
    //if index is out of scope terminate
    if(i >= els.length) return;
    var el = els[i];

    $(".middle tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)").text($(el).find("td:nth-child(1)").text());
    $(".middle tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)").text($(el).find("td:nth-child(2)").text());
    $(".middle tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(5)").text($(el).find("td:nth-child(3)").text());
    insRow(".middle", function(callback){
      if(callback){                                                        
        next(i+1);//proceed with the next element
      }
    });
})(0);//start immediately at index 0
```

Comment: Good work! I'm not used to writing the code like this... but yours works! I have tried this (https://jsfiddle.net/6wgygwcw/3/) ... is more clearfull for me, but still can not get it to work. Thanks

Comment: @francesco why dont you simply take mys?!

Comment: ? Exuse me, can you explain me?